# Tkinter bad window path name ".!Label" when calling previous function within another function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a pokedex with python and i was trying to make different pages with tkinter as a prototype and to get my head around its concept. i have the variables in a file called vardata.py, the functions in functions.py and the main thing in test.py. my main issue is this one function recalling a function within the same file.

this is what it looks like

```
import tkinter as tk
from vardata import *
import winsound as ws
def mainmenu():
    mainlabel1.place(x=100,y=100)
    pikabutton.place(x = 200, y = 100)
def enterpikachu():
    mainlabel1.destroy()
    pikabutton.destroy()
    photolabel.place(x=100,y=50) 
    pikalabel1.place(x=800,y=200)
    pikalabel2.place(x=800,y=250)
    pikalabel3.place(x=800,y=300)
    pikaquit.place(x = 1000, y = 500)
def quitpikachu():
    photolabel.destroy()
    pikalabel1.destroy()
    pikalabel2.destroy()
    pikalabel3.destroy()
    pikaquit.destroy()
    print("among") #for debugging
    mainmenu()
    print("sus") #for debugging
pikaquit = tk.Button(root,text = "Back", command = quitpikachu)
pikabutton = tk.Button(root,text = "Enter",command = enterpikachu)
```

when pressing on the button pikaquit it doesnt call mainmenu() for somereason giving me a bad window path name ".!Label" error and im not sure what that means. Anyone got a solution? also i saw a thread that referse to the button not having root within it but i made sure all my things did.

Variables for context

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

mainlabel1 = tk.Label(root,text = "Pikachu", font = "Ariel")
pika = tk.PhotoImage(file = "Assets/025.jpg")
photolabel = tk.Label(root)
photolabel.config(image = pika)
photolabel.image = pika
pikalabel1 = tk.Label(root,text="No25 Pikachu", font = ("Ariel", 25))
pikalabel2 = tk.Label(root,text="MOUSE Pokemon", font = ("Aeial", 15))
pikalabel3 = tk.Label(root,text="It has small electric sacks on both its cheeks.\nIf threatend, it releases the built up electricity.")
```

also the buttons pikabutton and pikaquit wouldnt work unless i put them in the functions file. i dont know why if i could ask for help on that as well that would be awesome.

I have tried putting the functions in different places as well as making a for loop to seperate the destroy commands but it was all in vain.

Comment: When `pikaquit` button is clicked, `quitpikachu()` will be executed and `photolabel` is destroyed.  Then if `pikabutton` is clicked, `enterpikachu()` will be executed and the line `photolabel.place(...)` will raise the exception because `photolabel` has already been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created your `pikaquit` correctly with reference to the window unless the button is not showing in your window correctly. I think the main issue is with the command given to the button.

If you want your `pikaquit` button to call `mainmenu()` you need to make your button call that function like so...

```
pikaquit = tk.Button(root ,text = "Back", command = mainmenu)
```

the way you have it now calls `quitpikachu()` instead which is fine as long as that function also calls `mainmenu()`. It looks like you are trying to pass a label instead of a window to the `mainmenu` within your `quitpikachu` function. But without seeing what the `mainmenu` and `quitpikachu` functions, I can't point out the exact issue.

But with reference to the buttons only working if they are put in the functions file, I'm assuming this is because this is where your command functions are located. What you should be able to do is classify them within `vardata.py` without specifying the command. Then you can configure the command from within the functions file instead. This should look something like this...

```
# This goes in your variables file
pikaquit = tk.Button(root, text = "Back")
pikabutton = tk.Button(root, text = "Enter")

# This goes in your functions file
pikaquit.configure(command = quitpikachu)
pikabutton.configure(command = enterpikachu)
```